# DELETE rows from two tables which do not have an id match to another query of the same two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

The following does not necessarily use correct syntax, but is intended to convey my intention:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta 
 WHERE wp_posts.ID <> min(f.post_ID), wp_postmeta.post_id <> min(f.post_ID)
```

(It's really two deletes combined in one, with the WHERE condition for the first and second table respectively.)

where `min(f.post_ID)` comes from the virtual table below:

```
SELECT Min(f.post_id), 
       f.post_title, 
       f.meta_value 
FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.post_title, 
               Min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice 
        FROM   wp_postmeta 
               JOIN wp_posts 
                 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
        WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
               AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
        GROUP  BY wp_posts.post_title) AS x 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                          wp_posts.post_title, 
                          wp_postmeta.meta_value 
                   FROM   wp_postmeta 
                          JOIN wp_posts 
                            ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
                   WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                          AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
                   ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_title, 
                             wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS f 
               ON x.post_title = f.post_title 
                  AND f.meta_value = x.minprice 
GROUP  BY f.post_title
```

How would the query look?

Edit: It's worth considering that any implementation that deletes from one table before the other will change the outcome of the second delete.  (The second DELETE will be affected by the first delete because items from the table in the sub query were deleted in the first DELETE.)

Comment: Intentions are much better conveyed by explanation, sample data, and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You don't delete from two tables at the same time. If the tables are related, you delete from the child, then the parent. If they're unrelated the delete may happen in any order. If they're unrelated but have other tables depending on them (i.e. they are parents themselves and have children) then data must be cleared out of those other tables first. If the relational constraints are set to CASCADE DELETE mode, then child table data will be deleted automatically when parent table data is deleted. If the delete must happen as an all or nothing affair (i.e. if the second delete fails after the first delete succeeds you don't want the first delete to succeed), it should be done in a transaction.

Thus:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id NOT IN (

  SELECT Min(f.post_id)
  FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.post_title, 
           Min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice 
    FROM   wp_postmeta 
           JOIN wp_posts 
             ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
    WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
           AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
    GROUP  BY wp_posts.post_title) AS x 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                      wp_posts.post_title, 
                      wp_postmeta.meta_value 
               FROM   wp_postmeta 
                      JOIN wp_posts 
                        ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
               WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                      AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
               ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_title, 
                         wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS f 
           ON x.post_title = f.post_title 
              AND f.meta_value = x.minprice 
  GROUP  BY f.post_title
)

DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN (

  SELECT Min(f.post_id)
  FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.post_title, 
           Min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice 
    FROM   wp_postmeta 
           JOIN wp_posts 
             ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
    WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
           AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
    GROUP  BY wp_posts.post_title) AS x 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                      wp_posts.post_title, 
                      wp_postmeta.meta_value 
               FROM   wp_postmeta 
                      JOIN wp_posts 
                        ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
               WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                      AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
               ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_title, 
                         wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS f 
           ON x.post_title = f.post_title 
              AND f.meta_value = x.minprice 
  GROUP  BY f.post_title
)
```

#### Warning

Don't run a delete query given to you by someone on the internet without backing your data up first. At the very least, start a transaction, run the delete, select the results and look at them to ensure they're correct, using the following code pattern:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM ...
DELETE FROM ...
SELECT * FROM ... -/*to check the deletes worked and didn't remove too much*/
ROLLBACK;
```

Change the ROLLBACK to COMMIT when you're happy

Edit:

#### Option 1

Make the posts meta depend on posts (it may do already, ensure the deletes are cascaded):

```
ALTER TABLE posts_meta
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_pm FOREIGN KEY (posts_id) REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Now run your delete on the posts table, posts_meta entries will also disappear

#### Option2

Run your delete on posts table as recommended above

Use the following query to delete any record from posts_meta that doesnt have a matching record in posts:

```
DELETE FROM posts_meta WHERE post_id IN (select post_id from(
  SELECT pm.post_id 
  FROM
    posts_meta pm
    LEFT JOIN 
    posts p
    ON p.id = pm.post_id
  WHERE
    p.id IS NULL

) i )
```

The innermost subquery that finds the id list is wrapped inside another subquery for a reason; there are situations where MySQL will refuse a delete if the pattern is `DELETE FROM x WHERE y IN (SELECT x FROM y)` because you can't modify a table you're selecting from. Wrapping it up in another select is a hack that causes MySQL to not treat it as deleting from the same table you're selecting from

Comment: The problem is I thought the delete on both tables needs to happen at the same time, because the second DELETE will be affected by the first delete, because items from the table in the sub query were deleted in the first DELETE.

Comment: In that case, your option is either to establish a foreign key relationship so that one is the parent and one is the child and ensure ON DELETE CASCADE is specified, then just delete from the parent and the related records in the child will be deleted as part of the operation, or you can delete from one table based on your existing query and then delete from the other table based on a LEFT JOIN that identifies missing records in the other table

Comment: I added some more to the answer to explain these

Comment: What is an easy way for me to check if `wp_postmeta` is already "dependent" on `wp_posts`?  If so, could I just delete from wp_posts and expect all corresponding `wp_postmeta` rows to be automatically deleted also?

Comment: To see if either table is already foreign keyed to the other: https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-see-foreign-key-relationship-of-a-table.html

Comment: But if you’re using phpmyadmin, can you not just have a poke around? It’s a web based GUI for mysql, afaik.. I’ve used it once and it looked pretty comprehensive

Comment: With respect to the `i`, I assume that's a table alias?  If so, is it equivalent to `AS i`?  Why don't you have the `AS` part in there?

Comment: Habit, maybe - I think it’s somehing of a de facto standard way of writing SQLs, that column names are aliased with AS and table names are aliased without. Take a look at any SQL on here written by someone who has high points in sql category; mostly they wrote this way. early versions of Oracle didn’t let you use AS to alias a table name, not sure about modern versions.. I learned on oracle 9, possibly many SQL experts have a similar heritage

Comment: Also, I see what you mean about the hack being necessary.  Without it, I get error `Table 'wp_postmeta' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data` in MariaDB [10.2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ebd356a6c59ff8bc27f445eb15bca4ce), but not in [10.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6ebfa4aaeb3ff6093839841633f667f8).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to select IDs to be deleted from tables `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` into temporary tables `posts` and `postmeta`. This will preserve a list of IDs even if you delete data from any table. Then delete data from tables `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` one after another based on the list of IDs in the temp tables. The last step is to clear temporary tables (delete data from them).

The transaction is used in that way to allow run this code in PHPMyAdmin.

The optimal version of the code:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS minPostIds AS 
    SELECT Min(f.post_id)
    FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.post_title, 
               Min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice 
        FROM   wp_postmeta 
               JOIN wp_posts 
                 ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
        WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
               AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
        GROUP  BY wp_posts.post_title) AS x 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                          wp_posts.post_title, 
                          wp_postmeta.meta_value 
                   FROM   wp_postmeta 
                          JOIN wp_posts 
                            ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
                   WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                          AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price') AS f 
               ON x.post_title = f.post_title 
                  AND f.meta_value = x.minprice 
        GROUP  BY f.post_title;


DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM minPostIds);
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM minPostIds); 

DELETE FROM minPostIds;

COMMIT;
```

This version works:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts AS 
    SELECT ID
    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE wp_posts.ID NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT Min(f.post_id)
        FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.post_title, 
                   Min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice 
            FROM   wp_postmeta 
                   JOIN wp_posts 
                     ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
            WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                   AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
            GROUP  BY wp_posts.post_title) AS x 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                              wp_posts.post_title, 
                              wp_postmeta.meta_value 
                       FROM   wp_postmeta 
                              JOIN wp_posts 
                                ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
                       WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                              AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
                       ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_title, 
                                 wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS f 
                   ON x.post_title = f.post_title 
                      AND f.meta_value = x.minprice 
            GROUP  BY f.post_title
);



CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postmeta AS     
SELECT post_id
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT Min(f.post_id)
        FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.post_title, 
                   Min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice 
            FROM   wp_postmeta 
                   JOIN wp_posts 
                     ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
            WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                   AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
            GROUP  BY wp_posts.post_title) AS x 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                              wp_posts.post_title, 
                              wp_postmeta.meta_value 
                       FROM   wp_postmeta 
                              JOIN wp_posts 
                                ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
                       WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                              AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
                       ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_title, 
                                 wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS f 
                   ON x.post_title = f.post_title 
                      AND f.meta_value = x.minprice 
            GROUP  BY f.post_title
);


DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM posts);

DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM postmeta);

DELETE FROM posts;
DELETE FROM postmeta;

COMMIT;
```

You can also create a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteFromTables()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts 
ENGINE=MyISAM 
AS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE wp_posts.ID NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT Min(f.post_id)
        FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.post_title, 
                   Min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice 
            FROM   wp_postmeta 
                   JOIN wp_posts 
                     ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
            WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                   AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
            GROUP  BY wp_posts.post_title) AS x 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                              wp_posts.post_title, 
                              wp_postmeta.meta_value 
                       FROM   wp_postmeta 
                              JOIN wp_posts 
                                ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
                       WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                              AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
                       ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_title, 
                                 wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS f 
                   ON x.post_title = f.post_title 
                      AND f.meta_value = x.minprice 
            GROUP  BY f.post_title
    )
);



CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postmeta
ENGINE=MyISAM 
AS (
    SELECT post_id
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT Min(f.post_id)
        FROM   (SELECT wp_posts.post_title, 
                   Min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice 
            FROM   wp_postmeta 
                   JOIN wp_posts 
                     ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
            WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                   AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
            GROUP  BY wp_posts.post_title) AS x 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
                              wp_posts.post_title, 
                              wp_postmeta.meta_value 
                       FROM   wp_postmeta 
                              JOIN wp_posts 
                                ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
                       WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
                              AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
                       ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_title, 
                                 wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS f 
                   ON x.post_title = f.post_title 
                      AND f.meta_value = x.minprice 
            GROUP  BY f.post_title 
    )
);


START TRANSACTION;

    DELETE FROM wp_posts
    WHERE wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM posts);

    DELETE FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM postmeta);

COMMIT;

DELETE FROM posts;
DELETE FROM postmeta;
END;
```

Comment: Regarding the `WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id <> min(f.post_ID)` part, I'm not sure if that stands on its own, because the full `SELECT Min(f.post_id)`derives from an entire other query.  Could you please modify your solution to include the original query from where `Min(f.post_id)` comes?

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of `Unrecognized` errors: `Unrecognized keyword` - can you help?  I'll paste the full error in my original post.  (Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution)

Comment: After removing the comment lines, I am still getting: `1 errors were found during analysis.  Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)`

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't made the error go away: `1 errors were found during analysis.
Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187787/discussion-between-jaro-and-ptrcao).